# Need dataweave help to do transformation

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

Input I have is given below

```
[
  {
    "CloudAccountDetail": {
      "CompanyCode": "B_B001",
      "CloudAccountId": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024",
      "CloudAccountPublicName": "dodp-testcloud",
      "Status": "SUBSCRIBED",
      "ClusterName": "ci.dev.cloudi.city"
    },
    "NamedSubscriptions": [
      {
        "SubscriptionId": "8f724cc9-bb21-43bc-8911-94d267eb7917",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST708259",
        "StartDate": "2020-01-07T12:13:19.507",
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-01-16T00:00:00",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-SA-PUSR",
        "ProductName": "Esko Cloud Power User",
        "Assignee": "eskododp03@yahoo.be",
        "AssignedBy": "LicenseService",
        "AssignedDate": "2020-01-07T11:16:52.723",
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      },
      {
        "SubscriptionId": "5c06112a-90a4-4e76-b2f4-bd19a1ce92b3",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST708259",
        "StartDate": "2020-01-07T12:13:19.507",
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-01-16T00:00:00",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-SA-PUSR",
        "ProductName": "Esko Cloud Power User",
        "Assignee": null,
        "AssignedBy": null,
        "AssignedDate": null,
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      },
      {
        "SubscriptionId": "a258a7fc-cff6-4b53-b19d-4e25a8dbcee6",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST708259",
        "StartDate": "2020-01-07T12:13:19.507",
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-01-16T00:00:00",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-SA-PUSR",
        "ProductName": "Esko Cloud Power User",
        "Assignee": null,
        "AssignedBy": null,
        "AssignedDate": null,
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      },
      {
        "SubscriptionId": "e30f16af-de60-4b84-bdae-aa7b6523c316",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST708259",
        "StartDate": "2020-01-07T12:13:19.507",
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-01-16T00:00:00",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-SA-PUSR",
        "ProductName": "Esko Cloud Power User",
        "Assignee": null,
        "AssignedBy": null,
        "AssignedDate": null,
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      },
      {
        "SubscriptionId": "5ee9eeb6-9d65-42b8-b594-68c9528ff25b",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST708259",
        "StartDate": "2020-01-07T12:13:20.507",
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-01-16T00:00:00",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-SA-PUSR",
        "ProductName": "Esko Cloud Power User",
        "Assignee": null,
        "AssignedBy": null,
        "AssignedDate": null,
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      },
      {
        "SubscriptionId": "818b38f1-0a10-45dc-ae16-f7d804b31cbc",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST708259",
        "StartDate": "2020-01-07T12:13:20.507",
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-01-16T00:00:00",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-SA-PUSR",
        "ProductName": "Esko Cloud Power User",
        "Assignee": null,
        "AssignedBy": null,
        "AssignedDate": null,
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      },
      {
        "SubscriptionId": "cf5fc421-8ee0-4f1f-a1ca-e64daef2e0c6",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST708259",
        "StartDate": "2020-01-07T12:13:20.507",
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-01-16T00:00:00",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-SA-PUSR",
        "ProductName": "Esko Cloud Power User",
        "Assignee": null,
        "AssignedBy": null,
        "AssignedDate": null,
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      }
    ],
    "UnnamedSubscriptions": [
      {
        "SubscriptionId": "c56c5d21-83dd-4df5-851c-52fd5686240b",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST708259",
        "StartDate": "2020-01-07T13:23:02.593",
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-01-16T00:00:00",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-SA-SITE",
        "ProductName": "Share & Approve Site",
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      },
      {
        "SubscriptionId": "1d5bf54c-e812-4c17-830d-d3a1104d66a5",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST708259",
        "StartDate": "2020-01-07T13:23:02.593",
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-01-16T00:00:00",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-SA-SITE",
        "ProductName": "Share & Approve Site",
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      },
      {
        "SubscriptionId": "fbe0bbef-3cc2-451a-9866-0bb31a829850",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST708259",
        "StartDate": "2020-01-07T13:23:02.593",
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-01-16T00:00:00",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-SA-SITE",
        "ProductName": "Share & Approve Site",
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      },
      {
        "SubscriptionId": "368fa144-5a94-4ead-ba69-502ca6419de4",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST708259",
        "StartDate": "2020-01-07T13:23:02.593",
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-01-16T00:00:00",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-SA-SITE",
        "ProductName": "Share & Approve Site",
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      },
      {
        "SubscriptionId": "3404fb6e-d234-4dac-a5a1-96c7534ccf21",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST708259",
        "StartDate": "2020-01-07T13:23:03.593",
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-01-16T00:00:00",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-SA-SITE",
        "ProductName": "Share & Approve Site",
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      },
      {
        "SubscriptionId": "71d88ad6-3108-499e-8be9-3638c7298770",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST708259",
        "StartDate": "2020-01-07T13:23:03.593",
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-01-16T00:00:00",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-SA-SITE",
        "ProductName": "Share & Approve Site",
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      },
      {
        "SubscriptionId": "992b551e-1499-4971-bc9b-34075820faa7",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST708259",
        "StartDate": "2020-01-07T13:23:03.593",
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-01-16T00:00:00",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-SA-SITE",
        "ProductName": "Share & Approve Site",
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      }
    ],
    "StorageSubscriptions": [
      {
        "EntitlementId": "5ceae026-5c3e-40df-a9f8-2de4f4570566",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST708259",
        "StorageInGb": 50,
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-01-07T00:00:00",
        "StartDate": "2020-01-07T12:37:12.697",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-ECL-ST-ST50",
        "ProductName": "Storage Tier 1 (50GB)",
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      }
    ],
    "TransactionSubscriptions": [
      {
        "EntitlementId": "6eaf4b93-8fef-4423-88fd-7e83d790f6f7",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST708259",
        "NumberOfTransactions": 12000,
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-01-07T00:00:00",
        "StartDate": "2020-01-07T12:17:56.257",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-ECL-BTR-BTR1000",
        "ProductName": "Basic Transactions Tier 2 (1000/m)",
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "CloudAccountDetail": {
      "CompanyCode": "B_B001",
      "CloudAccountId": "a-t-1001-0001-0039-0024",
      "CloudAccountPublicName": "Test-Tom-Desmet",
      "Status": "SUBSCRIBED",
      "ClusterName": "ci.dev.cloudi.city"
    },
    "NamedSubscriptions": [
      {
        "SubscriptionId": "3dc289af-d469-4dba-875e-354c75d2a31a",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST709894",
        "StartDate": "2020-06-30T14:21:34.773",
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-07-09T00:00:00",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-SA-PUSR",
        "ProductName": "Esko Cloud Power User",
        "Assignee": "eskododp03@yahoo.be",
        "AssignedBy": "LicenseService",
        "AssignedDate": "2020-06-30T13:31:01.777",
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1001-0001-0039-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      },
      {
        "SubscriptionId": "3e6818fb-1c4f-4046-9783-5b76d3050eec",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST709894",
        "StartDate": "2020-06-30T14:21:35.773",
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-07-09T00:00:00",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-SA-PUSR",
        "ProductName": "Esko Cloud Power User",
        "Assignee": null,
        "AssignedBy": null,
        "AssignedDate": null,
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1001-0001-0039-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      }
    ],
    "UnnamedSubscriptions": [
      {
        "SubscriptionId": "baf3d5c7-b53e-460e-93a5-311b95924fca",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST709894",
        "StartDate": "2020-06-30T15:18:15.593",
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-07-09T00:00:00",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-SA-SITE",
        "ProductName": "Share & Approve Site",
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1001-0001-0039-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      },
      {
        "SubscriptionId": "69071fd1-59b5-44ef-a594-95141d68ef4c",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST709894",
        "StartDate": "2020-06-30T15:18:16.593",
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-07-09T00:00:00",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-SA-SITE",
        "ProductName": "Share & Approve Site",
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1001-0001-0039-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      }
    ],
    "StorageSubscriptions": [
      {
        "EntitlementId": "f6f444e3-4dea-43d9-afc0-19d24200cf46",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST709894",
        "StorageInGb": 50,
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-06-30T00:00:00",
        "StartDate": "2020-06-30T14:57:54.05",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-ECL-ST-ST50",
        "ProductName": "Storage Tier 1 (50GB)",
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1001-0001-0039-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      }
    ],
    "TransactionSubscriptions": [
      {
        "EntitlementId": "22d25390-4183-4c89-8461-38ebf048812f",
        "OrderNumber": "TEST709894",
        "NumberOfTransactions": 12000,
        "ExpiryDate": "2021-06-30T00:00:00",
        "StartDate": "2020-06-30T14:24:10.017",
        "CanceledDate": null,
        "ProductCode": "ECL-ECL-BTR-BTR1000",
        "ProductName": "Basic Transactions Tier 2 (1000/m)",
        "EskoCloudAccount": "a-t-1001-0001-0039-0024",
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Output I need is given below. I am not able to create to separete elements in an array.

```
[
  {
    "key": "8f724cc9-bb21-43bc-8911-94d267eb7917",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16"
  },
  {
    "key": "5c06112a-90a4-4e76-b2f4-bd19a1ce92b3",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16"
  },
  {
    "key": "a258a7fc-cff6-4b53-b19d-4e25a8dbcee6",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16"
  },
  {
    "key": "e30f16af-de60-4b84-bdae-aa7b6523c316",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16"
  },
  {
    "key": "5ee9eeb6-9d65-42b8-b594-68c9528ff25b",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16"
  },
  {
    "key": "818b38f1-0a10-45dc-ae16-f7d804b31cbc",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16"
  },
  {
    "key": "cf5fc421-8ee0-4f1f-a1ca-e64daef2e0c6",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16"
  },
  {
    "key": "c56c5d21-83dd-4df5-851c-52fd5686240b",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16",
    "cloudPublicName": "dodp-testcloud",
    "cloudAccountId": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024"
  },
  {
    "key": "1d5bf54c-e812-4c17-830d-d3a1104d66a5",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16",
    "cloudPublicName": "dodp-testcloud",
    "cloudAccountId": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024"
  },
  {
    "key": "fbe0bbef-3cc2-451a-9866-0bb31a829850",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16",
    "cloudPublicName": "dodp-testcloud",
    "cloudAccountId": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024"
  },
  {
    "key": "368fa144-5a94-4ead-ba69-502ca6419de4",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16",
    "cloudPublicName": "dodp-testcloud",
    "cloudAccountId": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024"
  },
  {
    "key": "3404fb6e-d234-4dac-a5a1-96c7534ccf21",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16",
    "cloudPublicName": "dodp-testcloud",
    "cloudAccountId": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024"
  },
  {
    "key": "71d88ad6-3108-499e-8be9-3638c7298770",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16",
    "cloudPublicName": "dodp-testcloud",
    "cloudAccountId": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024"
  },
  {
    "key": "992b551e-1499-4971-bc9b-34075820faa7",
    "expiryDate": "2021-01-16",
    "cloudPublicName": "dodp-testcloud",
    "cloudAccountId": "a-t-1000-5001-0687-0024"
  },
  {
    "key": "3dc289af-d469-4dba-875e-354c75d2a31a",
    "expiryDate": "2021-07-09"
  },
  {
    "key": "3e6818fb-1c4f-4046-9783-5b76d3050eec",
    "expiryDate": "2021-07-09"
  },
  {
    "key": "baf3d5c7-b53e-460e-93a5-311b95924fca",
    "expiryDate": "2021-07-09",
    "cloudPublicName": "Test-Tom-Desmet",
    "cloudAccountId": "a-t-1001-0001-0039-0024"
  },
  {
    "key": "69071fd1-59b5-44ef-a594-95141d68ef4c",
    "expiryDate": "2021-07-09",
    "cloudPublicName": "Test-Tom-Desmet",
    "cloudAccountId": "a-t-1001-0001-0039-0024"
  }
  
]
```

Comment: You will have to provide more details on the rules to get each attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the rules to transform the data are not clear, I did my own take which seems to produce the expected result:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
flatten (
    payload map (item, order) -> (
        flatten ( [
            item.NamedSubscriptions map {
                key: $.SubscriptionId,
                expiryDate: $.ExpiryDate as Date
            } 
            , 
            item.UnnamedSubscriptions map {
                key: $.SubscriptionId,
                expiryDate: $.ExpiryDate as Date,
                cloudPublicName: item.CloudAccountDetail.CloudAccountPublicName,
                cloudAccountId: item.CloudAccountDetail.CloudAccountId
            }
        ] )
    )  
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **`flatten`** would remove an extra level of an array.

Example:

```
%dw 2.0
fun getSubscription(items) =
    (items default []) map {
        "key": $.SubscriptionId,
        "expiryDate": $.ExpiryDate as Date
    }
fun getUnsubscriptions(items, id, name) = 
    (items default []) map {
        "key": $.SubscriptionId,
        "expiryDate": $.ExpiryDate as Date,
        "cloudPublicName": name,
        "cloudAccountId": id
    }
output application/json
---
flatten (payload map (getSubscription($.NamedSubscriptions) ++ 
    getUnsubscriptions($.UnnamedSubscriptions, 
      $.CloudAccountDetail.CloudAccountId,
      $.CloudAccountDetail.CloudAccountPublicName)))
```

Using function **`fun`** would make it cleaner and readability.

Using **flatMap** and reused one function to extract Named and UnnamedS Subscription.

```
%dw 2.0
fun getData(items, account, isUnnamedSubscriptions) = 
    (items default []) map {
        "key": $.SubscriptionId,
        "expiryDate": $.ExpiryDate as Date,
        ("cloudPublicName": account.CloudAccountPublicName) if (isUnnamedSubscriptions),
        ("cloudAccountId": account.CloudAccountId) if (isUnnamedSubscriptions)
    }
output application/json
---
payload map (
    getData($.NamedSubscriptions, $.CloudAccountDetail, false)
    ++
    getData($.UnnamedSubscriptions, $.CloudAccountDetail, true)
) flatMap () -> $
```